Cloudflare is serving cache API responses to returning users and not to new users
I am facing an issue with my Cloudflare cache settings for an API endpoint. Despite configuring my Cloudflare page rules to cache content, the responses aren’t being served from the cache to new users, as expected. Below are the details of my current setup:
Cloudflare Page Rule Settings:

Incoming Request Matching: Custom filter expression
Cache Eligibility: Eligible for cache
Edge TTL: Use cache-control header if present, bypass cache if not
Browser TTL: Respect origin TTL
Cache Key Settings:

Cache deception armor: Disabled
Cache by device type: Disabled
Ignore query string: Disabled
Sort query string: Enabled


Serve Stale Content While Revalidating: Enabled
Do not serve stale content while updating: Disabled
Respect Strong ETags: Not selected
Origin Error Page Pass-through: Not selected
Placement: First rule

This is my API Response Headers:
Cache-Control: max-age=300, public,s-maxage=600
Once the API is cached the API should return the cached response to the next user that comes till the cached expires. I expected the API response to be cached at Cloudflare’s edge for the specified TTL, yet the data isn’t consistently served from the cache. Is there something incorrect in my configuration, or might I be missing an additional setting? Any guidance on why the API response might not be cached as expected would be greatly appreciated.


"I expected the API response to be cached at Cloudflare’s edge for the specified TTL, yet the data isn’t consistently served from the cache."

Cloudflare does not guarantee that they will store your data in the edge for that long. If your website isn't getting a lot of traffic, they will definitely clear your data from their edge cache to make room for other website's data that is getting more traffic. To guarantee that Cloudflare caches this data for the specified period, you would need to enable Cache Reserve. Note that this feature incurs an added cost, although in my experience it isn't very much.
Also, if your users are hitting different Cloudflare edge servers, then the data may be getting cached in one edge location, but the next user coming in through a different edge server will not get that cached value. Instead the new edge location will request the data from your origin server again, and cache it separately. To solve this so that Cloudflare caches user origin response once, and serves that response from all edge locations, you need to enable Tiered Cache. I honestly don't know why Cloudflare doesn't enable this by default, since the high number of edge servers in the Cloudflare network mean that cache hit percentages are really low without enabling this feature.
